# How to create a 'page counter' in a controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Post model, and I'm wanting to implement a way of counting the amount of times a post has been visited through the posts_controller so that I can eventually order posts by view count. So far I've created a migration to add a 'view count' column to by Post model:

```
class AddViewcountToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :view_count, :integer
  end
end
```

I basically want something in the PostsController show method to add one on to the view_count column every time the show action is accessed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You have 70% of the solution right there in the question. You just need to express your words in code. :) It seems that you're not very confident with databases/models. In this case (re-)reading the rails tutorial will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just increase this counter in your `show` action.

```
def show
  # ...
  @post.increment!(:view_count)
end
```

No magic here :)

Comment: added to this, add a default value of `0` to your migration, as such: `add_column :posts, :view_count, :integer, default: 0`

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/increment Initializes attribute to zero if nil and adds the value passed as by (default is 1).

Comment: Awesome, didn't realise it'd be so simple! Couldn't find anything when searching google for similar solutions so I guess I was using the wrong words, thanks :)

Comment: Be aware, if you have a huge amount of sides this will increase your database writes extremely. I would move this into a Sideqik worker.

Answer (score 0):

Use rails [`increment`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/increment) to achieve this

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_post, only: [:show]
  before_filter :increment_view_count, only: [:show]

  def show
    # ...
  end

  private

  def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def increment_view_count
    @post.increment(:view_count)
  end
end
```